# MS Sync Framework 2.1 data conflict

Tags: synchronization, microsoft-sync-framework

I am using MS Sync Framework 2.1 with `WCF`.
I want to give a choice to client to choose particular record upload and download, is it possible or not?

Ex.

**Server DB**

```
Client Id  Client Name 
1          Alex 
2          Tim 2 
3          John
```

**Client DB**

```
Client Id  Client Name 
1          Alex 1 
2          Tim 
3          John
```

choice to client :  Alex 1 (1) record upload and tim 2 (2) record download
If it is possible then how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

dynamic filtering is not supported out of the box in Sync Framework. You'll be better off hand coding what you want to achieve rather than force Sync Fx to work that way.